# Python tuple search

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to write a simple program that will let me enter a name and then it will search the employeeList to see if the person is a manager or not.  The person will be a manager if their employee number is `500` or larger.

So with `["David", 501]` for example, how do you specify just the number part in the conditional statement?  I have used item for the names but am not sure what to do to specify the numbers.  Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input = raw_input("Please enter name to determine if employee is a manager: ")

employeeList = [["Shawn", 500], ["David", 501], ["Ted", 14], ["Jerry", 22]]

for item in employeeList :
    print "Employee Name is: ", item
    if item == input and item >= 500:
        print "This person is a manager."
    else:
        print "This person is not a manager."
```

Comment: Using `input` as a variable name is not a good idea, [input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) is already the name of a function.

Comment: also your if clause is wrong, but you will notice it soon ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone and yes I did realize now that my if clause is wrong :)  I will remember about the input name as well for the future.

Comment: In addition, a `dict` is the correct data structure to solve this problem, not a `list` of `list`s.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi yup - agreed - my answer used that with a .get() default for invalid lookups...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use numeric indices to reference specific elements in a list.  Since you're using a list of lists, we can reference indices off of the `item` loop variable.

Here is your for-loop adjusted accordingly:

```
for item in employeeList:
  print "Employee name is: %s" % (item[0])
  if item[0] == input and item[1] >= 500:
    print "This person is a manager."
  else:
    print "This person is not a manager."
```

Answer (score 1):

`item[0]` will be the name, and `item[1]` their employee number.

Answer (score 1):

This really should be something as:

```
lookup = dict( (name, ' is a manager' if num >= 500 else ' is not a manager') for name, num in employeeList)
print '{}{}'.format(some_name_from_somewhere, lookup.get(some_name_from_somewhere, ' is not known'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that in your example you are not using a list of tuples but a list of list. tuples are defined with normal brackets

```
("I", "am", "a", "tuple")
```

#### Sequence access

In Python, `list` and `tuple` are [sequences](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), so they can be accessed with numeric indices

For lists:

`item = ["Shawn", 501]`, then you can do `item[0]` and `item[1]`.

For tuples, it's exactly the same:

`item = ("Shawn", 501)`, then you can do `item[0]` and `item[1]`.

#### Unpacking

When your tuples are small, 'opening' them - `unpacking` being the Python term - is also very handy

```
item = ("Shawn", 501)
name, number = item # We unpack the content of the tuple into some variables
```

#### Named tuples

Python 2.6 has introduced a [namedtuple()](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) type which you may find useful. With your example, you could do something like the following:

```
Employee = namedtuple("Employee", ['name', 'number'])
employeeList = [
    Employee("Shawn", 500),
    Employee("David", 501),
    Employee("Ted", 14],
    Employee("Jerry", 22)
]
for item in employeeList:
    if item.name == name and item.number >= 500:
        print "This person is a manager."
    else:
        print "This person is not a manager."
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of printing out every item in your list?

You only need to find the queried person and check if he/she is a manager

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input = raw_input("Please enter name to determine if employee is a manager: ")

employeeList = [["Shawn", 500], ["David", 501], ["Ted", 14], ["Jerry", 22]]
employeeDict = dict(employeeList)

if input in employeeDict:
    if employeeDict[input] > 500:
        print "This person is a manager."
    else:
        print "This person is not a manager."
else:
    print "This person is not an employee."
```